# Create UserControl in non-UI thread Silverlight 5 browser application

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 browser application.

There is a class

```
public class ActivityControl:UserControl {

    public void LoadSubControls() {
        //Creates Other UserControls, does calculations and is very slow..No refactoring..
    }
}
```

I need to create multiple instances of this class and call the method LoadSubControls on runtime.

```
public class BasicContainer:UserControl  {

    public void CreateMultipleActivityControls() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            ActivityControl c = new ActivityControl();  ====> I need to call this in a different thread but causes Invalid Cross Thread Exception

            c.LoadSubControls();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to create multiple UI Threads in order to avoid invalid cross thread exception?

I need multithreading for performance reasons and because the method call is very slow and the UI freezes.

Is there any way to call method `SetSyncronizationContext` (which is [SecurityCritical]) in Silverlight?

Comment: Are all controls directly seen in the gui? You could create them lazy?

Comment: In "LoadSubControls" method I do Measure Arrange UpdateLayout of subcontrols in order to generate an image. Do you mean that i should not run InitializeComponent()?

Comment: I'd also go for splitting your method into smaller chunks and only call back to the ui thread every time you really need to place a control in the ui.

Answer (score 3):

There is no avoiding creating these controls on the UI thread, but you could take advantage of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` from Task Parallel Library (TPL) to allow for asynchronous operations.

I've been able to do something like this in silverlight 5 with a structure like this. Got the original idea looking at the source for Caliburn.Micro.

The following is a subset that applies to what you want.

```
public interface IPlatformProvider {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Executes the action on the UI thread asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "action">The action to execute.</param>
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnUIThreadAsync(Action action);    
}
```

Here is the implementation.

```
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="IPlatformProvider"/> implementation for the XAML platfrom (Silverlight).
/// </summary>
public class XamlPlatformProvider : IPlatformProvider {
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public XamlPlatformProvider() {
       dispatcher = System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void validateDispatcher() {
        if (dispatcher == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not initialized with dispatcher.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Executes the action on the UI thread asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "action">The action to execute.</param>
    public Task OnUIThreadAsync(System.Action action) {
        validateDispatcher();
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        System.Action method = () => {
            try {
                action();
                taskSource.SetResult(null);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                taskSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        };
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```

You could either go down the constructor DI route to pass in the provider or use a static locator pattern like this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Access the current <see cref="IPlatformProvider"/>.
/// </summary>
public static class PlatformProvider {
    private static IPlatformProvider current = new XamlPlatformProvider();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current <see cref="IPlatformProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static IPlatformProvider Current {
        get { return current; }
        set { current = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to make your calls without blocking the main thread and freezing the UI

```
public class BasicContainer : UserControl {
    public async Task CreateMultipleActivityControls() {
        var platform = PlatformProvider.Current;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            await platform.OnUIThreadAsync(() => {    
                var c = new ActivityControl();     
                c.LoadSubControls();
            });    
        }
    }
}
```

if making multiple calls to the dispatcher caused any performance issues you could instead move the entire process to one acync call.

```
public class BasicContainer : UserControl {
    public async Task CreateMultipleActivityControls() {
        var platform = PlatformProvider.Current;
        await platform.OnUIThreadAsync(() => {
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {                    
                var c = new ActivityControl();     
                c.LoadSubControls();
            }    
        });
    }
}
```